# Creating an archiver executable and part of it is archiving files given from the command line arguments

Tags: c, image, file, command-line, archive

There can be as many files as possible, but there has to be at least one.
The form is "executable name" "flag" "archivename" "files....". How do I find out how many files are given in the command line? I know I have to use a loop. Then once I found out how many files there are, how do I fopen each file and fread through each file then put it all into an archive file? An archive file is binary, correct? I have to record how many files are given to me, then the name of each file, how long the names of each file is, the size of each file and then the contents of each file and then put it all into the archive file. No compression

Comment: `argc` is the total number of elements in `argv` (including the executable name in `argv[0]`). So `argc - 3` is the number of input files.

Comment: Are you following a pre-existing archive format standard or do you get to create your own?  You know how many arguments there are from `argc`, assuming you have `int main(int argc, char **argv)` for your main program.  You don't need a loop to find out how many files there are.  You do need a loop to iterate over the list of files.  Does your archive have a centralized dictionary or a distributed dictionary?  Do you record all the file size and name (and location in the archive) information at the top of the file (centralized), or do you have the information before each file in the archive?

Comment: Yes I have int main(int argc, char **argv), oh okay so does the terminal automatically know the value of argc? And then how do I loop through each file based on how many values are in argc? But the files are not listed until argv[3], so how do I make sure I'm looping only through the files and opening and writing them to the archive file? What would that loop look like?

Comment: `for (int i = 3; i < argc; i++) { …process argv[i]…; }` is roughly what the loop looks like.  You can complain if `argc <= 3` — not enough arguments (unless one of the options doesn't need any file names — a list option would probably only need the command name, flag, archive name (3 arguments) to list all the files.  You might need some minor adjustments to the loop if you use [`getopt()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html) to process option letters (starting at entry `optind` in the array, mainly — and your argument count check might be different, too).

Answer (score 0):

```
char *filenames[argc-3];
for(i = 3; i < argc; i++)
{
    filenames[i-3] = argv[i];
    printf("Files = %s\n", filenames
}
```

So that loop will find out how many argc arguments there are excluding the "executable" "flag" "archive name." Then following that, i will be how many files are in argc. And then filenames[] will store the files in the command line argument, correct? So how would I loop through that array and open each file and determine the size with a different function that I call?